# How can I run a predefined batch script on a server through a web client?

Tags: javascript, html, client-server

**Background:**

I have a web server and a few clients that connect to the server via a website. I can do normal things such as GET and POST requests. However, I need to remove certain files from the server when a certain button is clicked on the web page. I am using JS to handle asynchronous events.

Basically, I want to run a predefined server-side batch script on the server when an html button is clicked.

**Things I've Tried**

I have tried using an ActiveXObject using

```
var webShell = new WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell");
webShell.Run("C:/FULL_PATH")

var webShell = new WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell");
webShell.Run("C:\\FULL_PATH")
```

I have the server pulled up on a second screen, but I don't see PowerShell popping up to execute any of the batch commands. When I get it to work, this only works on Internet Explorer.

Is there a way to run predefined batch scripts on the server that works with most web browsers?

Comment: Why not stand up an endpoint on the server that your client makes an ajax request to, that kicks off the batch script?

Comment: @Taplar This works. Thank you!